# Cookies signing with hash to validate integrity. Good idea?

Tags: php, validation, security, cookies, hash

I would like to know if it is a good idea to sign cookies with hash to check it's integrity? First of all, I do realize that I should not store any sensitve data in cookies and use sessions instead. That's exactly what i do. But still I am feeling not comfortable with user being able to modify even not so important data. (I'm kind of security paranoic :) )

I came up with the following solution. Let's say we have cookies for:

- PHPSESSID
- site_lang
- recently_viewed

Now whenever I update cookie value I recalculate hash for cookie with key of let's say `cookie_hash` and value of let's say `md5(serialize($_COOKIE)+$secret)` 
the only thing that I am not using PHPSESSID for calculation and validating hash because it is not being managed by CookieManager class (my custom class) and might be refreshed with new session id and corrupt hash. 
My concern is what if some third-party package sets it's own cookie bypassing my CookieManager of course. it will collapse hash. So is it a good idea at all?

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is weak for this, and the scheme you proposed (`hash(data||secret)`) is flawed anyway. Cryptography is hard, please don't try to come up with your own. :)

What you may be looking for is invented already, it's called message authentication. Have a look at things like [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), which is one proper way to do something very similar.

In most cases, authenticating cookie values doesn't make sense in a web application and provides no additional security, but there *are* cases, when it does. Your examples above don't seem so. :) For example the session id is cryptographically random already, and the other two usually present no harm if changed by a user (but in very special cases, they probably may, though I can't come up with a reasonable example). If something matters and should not be changed by the client (user), that should probably be stored in a server-side session.

However, you may decide to store application state on the client in encrypted and/or authenticated cookies, one reason for that may be a stateless application on the server (see the default session management in Ruby on Rails for example), and in that case, something like your idea (but done correctly) is indeed the solution, but it has its own set of risks (as do server-side sessions).

Note that anytime you store state on the client, one threat that comes up besides secrecy and authenticity is replay. This affects your idea as well. Say it is a problem in your application if the user can change the last_viewed cookie, but you still don't want to put it in the session. You properly authenticate the cookie, maybe even encrypt it, the client has no access. But what if at some point, the user saves the cookie, and in a different session replays it? (Okay, your example tries to protect all cookies at once, which may make this a little bit more difficult, but you get the idea, replay is still a potential problem.)

So in short, you most probably don't need this, but if you do, then use proper message authentication (something like an [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), or a proper MAC like HMAC).

Comment: Thank you for providing detailed answer. My app doesn’t actually need this level of security so i was thinking about some drop-in quick solution and not using maybe some time-proven solutions for this. (But of course if it was crucial for my app i would look into it). I was wondering  if this exact “dirty” trick could do the thing and possible pitfalls with this solution. Also I realize that md5 is quite weak but i thought for this trivial task it was enough...can you please tell me more what is wrong with simple hash of value+secret for basic security?

Comment: And yes, replay is a potential problem. thank you for pointing it out. (forgot about it entirely) maybe some fingerprinting based on ip will do the trick?

Comment: But again...I would have definitely done a complete research on the topic if it was crucial for my app...but for this project it is not important. so my question is more of 'why not doing this if it's fairly simple to implement or if it has too many pitfalls not doing it all? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how deep you digged in PHP and Webdevelopment, so please forgive me if the level of my answear is to low.

If you are paranoid you should read more about PHP, sessions, cookies, hashing algorithms and more.

For example:

[PHP session handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

[PHP session configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

[PHP session security](http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php)

With this you can modify your sessions & your handling a little bit to serve your paranoia.

By the way you shouldn't use something like md5 in reference to make your web application more secure.

---

If i understand what you want to do, you want to write a hash of your serialized session array plus a secret/salt **into the session** to verify the integrity of the session and its data.

If this is your motivation, you really should rethink, at least in my opinion.

A session is just a file on your server (on the users system it's a database entry in a sqlite database of firefox or something else, but without the data you write to the cookie array, that data are just writen to the server) and the session ID is a file name/path to this data on the server, except your sessions are saved on a database.

So with your approach you would just save the value to verify the integrity of the data in the same data (on the server) you want to verify.

And where you want to save the secret?

I think it's a little bit useless.

Depending on your needs and the needs of your application you could search about the key word session TAN, you could set a additional cookie with a random value you save on the session to verify each other, you could save and check the IP (depending on the law of your country and the way your users connect), shorten the session lifetime and more.

You could also set ini directives like session.cookie_httponly (that's one i recommend if you don't want to access your session cookie by a script language like JavaScript) you can find on the links above and more.

Something is a matter of faith, something evident.

Digg in deeper and understand how the technology works under the hood and you can make your decision more easy by yourself.

Comment: Sorry, i am not talking about sessions here at all. Only cookie values.

Comment: No, i am sorry. I missed the point. Possibly it was a little to late.

Comment: But to clarify your question to me: What you want to do exactly when you say "sign cookies with hash"? What exactly you want to do with the result of `md5(serialize($_COOKIE)+$secret)`, where do you save it; on the session, a database, a textfile, the POST array (it's more a joke, but some people doing crazy things)? But generally i think it's not a bad idea to verify the integrity of data a user could manipulate. If you done everything you could do to minimized the risk (beside you can turn off the risk) it's not a kind of security by obscurity or something else, at least for me.

Comment: `md5(serialize($_COOKIE)+$secret)` is stored as cookie with key `cookie_hash`. I then check if this value is correct for current cookie values (except for keys PHPSESSID and cookie_hash itself)

Comment: Okay, now i got it. You shouldn't save `md5(serialize($_COOKIE)+$secret)` on a cookie, because the value is saved by the user. So you would try to verify untrusted data by a value that you got from a possibly untrusted source. You should save your verification key on a source like the session, a database or something else that's on the server side.

Comment: @Marc But the user doesn't have the secret, he can't make a valid cookie hash, so the idea is valid, only the implementation in the question is flawed (and I agree the whole thing is pointless for most use cases), see my answer.

Comment: @Gabor Lengyel Yes you are right. But it's even though the principles: "never trust user data" and "don't store security relevant data on a untrusted source".

Comment: @Marc Well, yes and no. Never trust user data - sure, unless you have a good reason, and message authentication can indeed be that good reason. You can argue that it is not even user data - it is a message from the server to itself, sent through an insecure channel which is the user, but protected against tampering by a MAC. Also don't store security relevant data on an untrusted source - again, unless you properly protect it, and an authenticated encryption for example can be a viable solution. Session management in Rails is entirely cookie based (no server side), and it is reasonably secure.

Comment: But as detailed in my answer to some extent, it is still a can of worms, replay is the most common issue when state is stored on the client.